# WSO2 Identity Server: Error while loading Identity Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 SP1. I'm receiving an error when I click on the `"Resident Identity Provider"` link in the admin website. This error message is `"Error while loading Identity Provider"`. I'll include the stack from the log file at the end of this post.

So far, all I have configured is a secondary user store which is connected to an Active Directory server. The users and groups are being displayed in the users/roles screens. I do get another error if I click on the User Profile link.

I have installed new SSL certificates for the Identity Server and updated the XML config files to use the hostname instead of localhost.

Does anyone have any suggestions what may be wrong? What I'm trying to do is test if I can login the the WSO2 dashboard with a user from the active directory - so far everything has failed.

**Error from logs:**

```
>     IdentityProviderMgtServiceIdentityApplicationManagementExceptionException
>     TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-03-06 14:06:39,690] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient} -
> IdentityProviderMgtServiceIdentityApplicationManagementExceptionException
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
> Source) java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub.IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.getResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.java:1307)
> org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.getResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.java:86)
> org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dload_002dlocal_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dload_002dlocal_jsp:91)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700)
> sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
> org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
> org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603) org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
> org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
> org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
> org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
> org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
> org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case others hit this - it seems the problem is if you use a certificate alias other than 'wso2carbon' in the JKS keystore when you change the SSL certificate.