# WSO2 Tenant Updation fails v5.5.0

Tags: wso2, migration, upgrade, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

After migrating to v5.5.0, This error happens when this tenant is updated. Other tenants are working fine. And tenant is not able to login. 
I have disabled org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener with orderId 95. Then I can login into the tenant.

I also found a [relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900763/wso2-identity-server-error-while-loading-identity-provider) and found tenant's Resident Identity Provider is throwing "Error loading Resident Identity Provider" and Keystore list page displays "Error occurred null".

The answer states,

> In case others hit this - it seems the problem is if you use a
>   certificate alias other than 'wso2carbon' in the JKS keystore when you
>   change the SSL certificate.

As a novice in WSO2, I can't seem to get what it means. During the migration, I used the same wso2carbon.jks file from the old version(5.1.0). Also found old version also has the same Resident Identity Provider and Keystore list page errors.

How can I resolve this error? I can see that keystore for that tenant is not available. How do I create a keystore for a tenant?

> ````
> {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.util.TenantMgtUtil} -  Error in adding
> claims to the user.  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException:
> Error when handling event : PRE_SET_USER_CLAIMS   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:619)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:572)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPreSetUserClaimValues(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:142)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1430)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.util.TenantMgtUtil.addClaimsToUserStoreManager(TenantMgtUtil.java:349)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.services.TenantMgtAdminService.updateTenant(TenantMgtAdminService.java:417)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)     at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:441)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.stub.TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.updateTenant(TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.java:2362)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.clients.TenantServiceClient.updateTenant(TenantServiceClient.java:110)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil.updateTenantConfigBean(TenantMgtUtil.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.jsp.tenant_002dmgt.submit_005ftenant_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(submit_005ftenant_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:167)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)    at
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.IdentityEventException: Error while
> getting connector configurations for property
> :account.disable.handler.enable   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.util.AccountUtil.getConnectorConfig(AccountUtil.java:68)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountDisableHandler.handleEvent(AccountDisableHandler.java:131)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.services.IdentityEventServiceImpl.handleEvent(IdentityEventServiceImpl.java:56)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:604)
>   ... 80 more Caused by:
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.IdentityGovernanceException: Error
> while retrieving resident Idp for test.com tenant.    at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.getConfiguration(IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.java:108)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.getConfiguration(IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.java:131)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.util.AccountUtil.getConnectorConfig(AccountUtil.java:61)
>   ... 83 more Caused by:
> org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManagementException: Could not
> find Resident Identity Provider for tenant test.com   at
> org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager.getResidentIdP(IdentityProviderManager.java:311)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.getConfiguration(IdentityGovernanceServiceImpl.java:105)
>   ... 85 more TID: [-1234] [] [2019-04-09 15:46:18,571] ERROR
> {org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil} -  Failed to
> update the tenant config. tenant-domain: test.com, tenant-admin:
> admin. 
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.stub.TenantMgtAdminServiceExceptionException:
> TenantMgtAdminServiceExceptionException   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.stub.TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.updateTenant(TenantMgtAdminServiceStub.java:2376)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.clients.TenantServiceClient.updateTenant(TenantServiceClient.java:110)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tenant.mgt.ui.utils.TenantMgtUtil.updateTenantConfigBean(TenantMgtUtil.java:119)
>   at
> org.apache.jsp.tenant_002dmgt.submit_005ftenant_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(submit_005ftenant_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:167)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
>   at
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)    at
> org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>   at
> org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ```
> ````

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this, although I'm not sure if this is the solution. I'm hoping this would help someone or someone could help me.

For tenant update throwing error `Failed to update the tenant config. tenant-domain: test.com, tenant-admin: admin`:

> Disable the Identity Listener `org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener` with `orderId` 95. Now in the admin user, you will be able to update the tenant.

The IdentityMgtEventListener with orderId 95 has to be disabled to login into the tenant for resolving keystore and Resident Identity Provider Issues.

For the keystore page throwing `Error occurred null`:

> Create a keystore for the tenant and add the keystore. These links were helpful:
>
> [Changing the hostname](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Changing+the+hostname)
>
> [How to changing the primary keystore of a tenant in carbon products](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/05/how-to-changing-the-primary-keystore-of-a-tenant-in-carbon-products/)

For the Resident Identity Provider throwing `Error loading Resident Identity Provider`:

> I found the tenant doesn't have an entry in the IDP table. So, I inserted a record for the tenant using the tenant id and this was resolved. Not sure if this is the right solution.
>
> Sample MySQL query:
>
> `INSERT INTO database.IDP ('ID', 'TENANT_ID', 'NAME', 'IS_ENABLED', 'IS_PRIMARY', 'HOME_REALM_ID', 'INBOUND_PROV_ENABLED', 'IS_FEDERATION_HUB', 'IS_LOCAL_CLAIM_DIALECT') VALUES ('72', '10', 'LOCAL', '1', '1', 'localhost', '0', '0', '0')`;